# Burn .IMG to another MicroSD Card without root

Tags: sd-card, images

Long story, I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and the only device I own that can write a Raspbian image to MicroSD is my Android phone. I have copied the image from my laptop to my MicroSD, but I am puzzled as to how I can write the IMG to the MicroSD, as rooting will void my warranty. MicroSD is necessary since the Raspberry Pi will not boot from USB.

Comment: Not possible to access block devices without root.

Answer (score -1):

- Copy the IMG file to the internal storage
- Download [EtchDroid [NO ROOT] - Write ISOs and DMGs to USB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.depau.etchdroid) from Play Store
- Select raw image or ISO (do these steps after the SD card has been plugged in)
- Select the IMG file and the SD card
- Wait until it completes the progress (it is possible to check the progress in the taskbar/notification)
- Done

Comment: The app makes use of USB host APIs to access USB drives, not SD cards.

Comment: EtchDroid reports sd card as an unsuitable usb!